# Using SD-Card as internal memory, but how?

Tags: sd-card, 6.0-marshmallow, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

I am confused, I installed today the Marshmallow update on my HTC One m8. I knew that there is a feature to use my SD card as internal memory and I was awaiting this feature. I did what I expected formatting the SD card and I can see the memory but dammed my internal memory is still full. Not more memory at all! Just a second non removable storage which is empty.

I tried to install a huge game (<1GB) but it failed since I have not enough memory. Dammed I just formatted a 64GB SD card! Sh...

So my question is did I something wrong or is it intended that I cannot use the SD card for games?

What is with other media? Can I store files on the "extended" internal memory?

For now it looks like I just reduced my internal memory by installing marshmallow without any memory related benefits. (I am a developer so I know other cool things)

Comment: You should be able to move supported apps to the adoptable storage: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/adoptable.html (last paragraph of first section)